# unlock Mac Time machine HDD in Ubuntu

Tags: macbook, external-hdd, info

I recently migrated from snow leopard to Ubuntu, but I forgot to make a backup of some of the info in my old mac. I have my time machine prepared HDD, but when I connect the drive to Ubuntu it tells me I do not have permission to see the content of the folders, any Ideas to open the drive and extract the info?

Answer (score 0):

I think the time machine volume is journaled. As I know Ubuntu cannot write on journaled format without some stuff. If you have your Mac available, plug in the Installer DVD/USB into and run the Disk Utilities from there and disable journaling on your time machine. Maybe this helps. Or you install some stuff to enable HFS+ Writing. (see this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write) from superuser.com)

I suggest the permission-error comes from ownership, cause you are not the owner of the folders and files. So you could try to run chown command?

Comment: The original poster in this question is unable to mount the volume at all, even to read its contents. In contrast, Ubuntu is typically able to mount HFS+ volumes, even if they are journalled--just not for write.